# Problem moving events in fullcalendar-angular

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm using [Fullcalendar-Angular](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular) and I'm trying to make events move from day to another but the problem is when I start pulling some event it has to be moved to the center of the cell of the new day.

I want the event to be moved **once the mouse enters the cell** of the new day.

Here are 2 pictures of what I mean .. I'm moving the event from day 16 to day 15.

Moved the event slightly before the center of the cell of day 15 **-- NOT activated**

[image]

Moved it a little further to the left **-- Activated**

[image]

This is kinda acceptable when in **Month view** as it changes the background color as an indicator, however when I move to **Week view** and start pulling it doesn't change the background nor does it move the event until it reaches the center of the new cell which causes usability issues when I'm trying to move the event on top of another event.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo-owkdzf)

What I tried

1. Using a 3rd-party library for dragging (Dragula)
2. Using the [eventDragMinDistance attribute](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDragMinDistance) but couldn't get how to calculate the correct value

Comment: From what I can observe, it's not the centre of the cell which is important. It's simply that at least 50% of the event element must be inside the new cell when you release the mouse. That seems pretty reasonable - it makes it clear you definitely intended to move it to there.

Comment: eventDragMinDistance doesn't seem to be relevant to this issue, from the (admittedly brief) description in the documentation. It seems to be more about when the dragging _starts_, as opposed to what the eventual target is.

Comment: Anyway this is built-in functionality of fullCalendar I think, so there's not a lot we can do here to fix it. You'd have to modify the fullCalendar source code somewhere. Unless someone on here is an expert on that code you're unlikely to get advice on what to do, other than to go to GitHub and start reading, or to make a feature request to the maintainers - maybe to add an option to change the threshold for dropping an event.